# Clicking a checkbox containing a specific string

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Am trying to click a checkbox that contains the string `12345-01` in the following code:

```
<tr class="dividebelow">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;12345-01&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>x small</td>
    <td>             
        <input class="12345_checkbox" name=“other" value=“5601" type="checkbox">                
    </td>
</tr>

    <tr class="dividebelow">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;12345-02&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>small</td>
    <td>
        <input class="12345_checkbox" name=“other" value="5602" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="dividebelow”>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;12345-03&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>medium</td>
    <td>
        <input class=“12345_checkbox" name=“other" value="5603" type="checkbox">                   
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have been unsuccessful to even find that string using `BeautifulSoup` and `findAll(text='12345-01')` and none of the `Selenium` `find_element` have worked so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those non breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) are also part of text value of that node. Try:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//td[text() = "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a012345-01\u00a0\u00a0"]')
```

You can select input with:

```
'//td[text() = "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a012345-01\u00a0\u00a0"]/parent::*//input'
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working! How do you suggest I select the box underneath?